# Why does AngularJS `orderBy` filter ignore the `comparator` parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to order an array of objects by using a `comparator` function, but it seems the `comparator` function is completely ignored (See the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)).

I am using angularJS 1.5.6.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxeosh8o/3/)

**Html:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{msg}}
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module("app", [])

.factory('f1', function($filter) { 

    var f1 = {};

    function comparator(a,b) { console.log(a,b); return a.id - b.id; }
    function getter(x) { /*console.log(x);*/ return x; }

    f1.testOrderBy = function() {
        return $filter('orderBy')(
            [ {id:3}, {id:1}, {id:2} ], 
            getter, 
            false, 
            comparator
        )
        .map(function(x) { return x.id; })
    };

    return f1;
})

.controller("ctrl", function($scope, f1) {
    $scope.msg = f1.testOrderBy();
})
```

**My question**: Why is `comparator` ignored? (This can be seen since the `console.log()` call is never made). Is this an angularJS bug?

*Because of this I cannot even order an array of objects using a custom comparator.*

Thanks!

Comment: surprisingly the plunker example they gave on site is also not working as they explained in the documentation https://plnkr.co/edit/FSq6AwlpdCRmTEQ7hefL?p=preview

Comment: Great catch Deep!  Didn't even notice that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the support for custom comparators in `orderBy` was added in **1.5.7**.

You can read the changelog [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

If you check the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for **1.5.6** you will see that the api is described as:

```
$filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse)
```

While in **1.5.7** it is:

```
$filter('orderBy')(collection, expression, reverse, comparator)
```

Comment: Thanks tasseKATT. Don't even know what to say. RTCFM.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't feel bad, many have done similar mistakes, including myself :)